# How can we show date picker in angular semantic ui?

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I have been trying to open date picker but it doesn't do anything. My code is as below.

```
      <div class = "ui calendar" id="birthDate">
        <div class = "ui input left icon">
          <i class = "calendar icon"></i>
          <input type="text" name="birthDate" placeholder="Birth date" ngModel>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is missing or what's wrong here?

Comment: <datepicker> <input ng-model="date" type="text"/></datepicker>

Comment: @sami I am getting this error in console.
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'datepicker' is not a known element

Comment: Are you included angular in your application

Comment: It's an angular app.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datepicker

Comment: I am using angular 4. It's not angular js.

Comment: https://angular.io/

Comment: Done with help of below article.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-io-datepicker and
https://github.com/rd-dev-ukraine/angular-io-datepicker/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts